# How to copy an entire directory using artifact? (Jenkins)

Tags: jenkins

How to copy an entire directory(with subdirectories) using artifact in jenkins ?
i tried like this : /lib/
but jenkins does not copy the subdirectories

Answer (score 1):

You can use `**` to indicate "any directory path"

`/lib/**/*`